# reactQuery returns undefined as the first result, then returns the data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

So, I'm trying to fetch data -onClick- using reactQuery and to **store the response in a variable**.

```
const { data: response, refetch } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['get-response'],
    queryFn: async() => {
        return await Axios.get('URL').then((res) => res.data);
    },
        enabled: false, //to allow refetch() onClick
    });

    const onSubmit = async () => {
        await refetch();
        console.log(response) // logs undefined 
        anotherFunctionThatWillUseResponse(response)
    };
    //if I console.log(response) here it will later show the response
```

I know I can use `useEffect` to listen on the response and do whatever inside of the useEffect, but I'm wondering why it returns undefined first, and how to properly handle this behavior

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behavior. When you call the `refetch` function, it re-renders the component, but runs the `onSubmit` function before that. So the states are the same (old). To fix this, add an `onSuccess` handler with useQuery hook.

```js
const { data: response, refetch } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['get-response'],
    queryFn: async () => {
        return await Axios.get('URL').then((res) => res.data);
    },
    onSuccess(response) {
        console.log(response); // logs the response
        anotherFunctionThatWillUseResponse(response);
    },
    enabled: false, // to allow refetch() onClick
});

const onSubmit = async () => {
    await refetch();
};
```

Comment: No problems, if this answer solved your problem, please accept it as solution or best answer

Answer (score -1):

because the data is still loading if you add isloading like this

```
const { data: response, refetch , islLoading }
```

and replace

```
    console.log(response) // logs undefined
```

with

```
  console.log(islLoading ) // you will get true
```

Comment: OP wants to get the response, not `isLoading`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).